# ValueError using np.loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to extract data from a txt file with numpy and I get this big error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python36\machine learning\bayes_classifier.py", line 14, in 
<module>
  data = np.loadtxt(input_file, delimiter=",")
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1092, in loadtxt
for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1019, in read_data
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1019, in <listcomp>
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 738, in floatconv
return float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ï»¿2.18'
```

notice the ValueError, what is the 'ï»¿2.18'?

Here is the full code:

```
### Naïve bayes classifier ###

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn import cross_validation

from utilities import visualize_classifier

# Input file containing data
input_file = "data_multivar_nb.txt"

# Load data from input file
data = np.loadtxt(input_file, delimiter=",")

x, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]
```

and here is the file:

[file link here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Artificial-Intelligence-with-Python/blob/master/Chapter%2002/code/data_multivar_nb.txt)

Comment: _notice the ValueError, what is the 'ï»¿2.18'?_ I assume it was found in the input file.

Comment: check the file, its not there, thats why I dont understand, there is only numbers and commas in it

Comment: How are you checking the file?  Are you using a plain text editor like `vi`?  How was that file created?

Comment: I found how to make it work, I had copy paste the content of the file in a txt file. This time I saved directly from github and it worked without errors, I guess the copy paste took in some unnecessary data that made np.loadtxt angry